# Adding shipping cost Woocommerce displays once and then reload summary and it disapears

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am adding input in Shipping section of Woocommerce checkout summary section. It's all working but when I add some value and press add cost button it refreshes and show value for sometime and then hide it.

What actually I want is if someone enters address and that not lies in our shipping areas then user will ask for shipping quote and we will send customer an email with pricing then user will add shipping cost in shipping cost field.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', 'change_noship_message' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', 'change_noship_message' );

function change_noship_message() {
    print "<p class='cust_shiipping_msg'>There are no shipping options available in your area. Please click the below button to get shipping cost by email.</p>
           <br>
           
        <form method='post' action=''  class='cust_shiipping_msg'>
            <input class='tanzil' type='submit' name='send' value='Get Shipping Quote'>
       
        </form>
      echo  "<p class='cust_shiipping_msg'>OR Put shipping cost in the below field if you already have received by email</p>";
      ?>
        <form  method="post" name="checkt"  class="cust_shiipping_msg" action="">
        <input type="text"  name="add_shipping_cost">
         <br /><br />
        <input class="tanz" type="submit" name="submited" value="add cost">

      </form>
      
<?php
   
              
     $rates = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
        
          if($_POST['send']) {
     
            global $woocommerce;
            global $product;
            global $cart;
            $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
            $prod_items =  array();
            $prod_qty = array();
            $prod_price = array();


                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                $prods= $cart_item['product_id'];
                $_product =  wc_get_product( $cart_item['data']->get_id());
                $prod_items[] = $_product->get_title();
                $prod_qty[] = $cart_item['quantity'];
                $prod_price[] = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'] , '_price', true);  

            }
             
                $sendto     =  "perola@merchans.se";
                $sendfrom   =  "perola@merchans.se";
                $sendsub    =  "perola@merchans.se";
                $sendmess   =  "<h3>Product Details</h3>";

                $sendmess  .= "<br>";
               $result =  array_merge($prod_items, $prod_qty, $prod_price);
               
                foreach($prod_items as $v){
                    foreach($prod_qty as $w){
                     foreach($prod_price as $x){


                $sendmess  .=  'product Name:'.$v;
                $sendmess  .= "<br>";
                $sendmess  .=  'product Qty:'.$w;
                $sendmess  .= "<br>";

                $sendmess  .=  'product Price:'.$x;
                $sendmess  = "<br>";
                break;
                }
                    
            break;
            }
            
            }            

        $headers[]  =  'Content-Type: text/html';
        $headers[]  =  'charset=UTF-8';
        $headers[]  =  "From: Wordpress <" . $sendfrom . ">";
        wp_mail($sendto, $sendsub, $sendmess, $headers); 
        echo "email sent";
    } 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wpc_add_cart_fee', 20, 1 );
function wpc_add_cart_fee() {  
global $woocommerce;


if($_POST['submited'])
          
$extra_shipping_cost = $_POST['add_shipping_cost'];  

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {  
    
    $_product = $values['data'];  

      
    $custom_shipping_cost = get_post_meta($_product->id, 'custom_shipping_cost', true); 


} 


if ($extra_shipping_cost) { 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping Cost', 'woocommerce'), $extra_shipping_cost ); 
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWZDt.png)
Check this image

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for the edit. Do you have any idea how i can do it?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please have a look on it. Thanks